# Make notes global?

Tags: global, public, odoo-9

I have a client who wants to use notes and have them global across all users. It would be easiest to just remove the user dependency to display to all users. The other option is to add `message_follower_ids` upon creation to add a "general" channel as a follower but I'm clueless as to what the values would be.

Any thoughts, ideas, advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve using two methods.

1. You can **inactive** record rule of note.

   ```
   <record id="note.note_note_rule_global" model="ir.rule">
       <field name="name">Only followers can access a sticky notes</field>
       <field name="model_id" ref="note.model_note_note"/>
       <field name="active" eval="False"/>
       <field name="domain_force">['|', ('user_id', '=', user.id), ('message_partner_ids', '=', user.partner_id.id)]</field>
       <field name="global" eval="True"/>
       <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
       <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
   </record>
   ```

   If you inactive above record rule then odoo will visible notes to all users.
2. Add **followers** inside note.

If you hide **some** notes for **some** users then you must not **inactive** record rule and just add followers.

This may help you.

Comment: I've actually commented out the whole file as all of those should be global. However, I keep frequently getting a Session Expired error message now.

Comment: `File "/opt/odoo/src/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 174, in _dispatch
    return self._handle_exception(e)
  File "/opt/odoo/src/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 172, in _dispatch
    auth_method = self._authenticate(func.routing["auth"])
  File "/opt/odoo/src/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 105, in _authenticate
    getattr(self, "_auth_method_%s" % auth_method)()
  File "/opt/odoo/src/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 81, in _auth_method_user
    raise http.SessionExpiredException("Session expired")
SessionExpiredException: Session expired`